# Trying to upload multiple images to firestore with Nodejs (ClientSide firebase SDK)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to upload multiple images to firestore in my nodeJS server-side code.
I initially implemented it with the firestore bucket API

```
admin.storage.bucket().upload()
```

I am placing the above code in a for loop.

```
for(let x = 0; images.length > x; x++){
  admin.storage.bucket().upload(filepath, {options}).then(val => {
    //get image download URL and add to a list
    imageUrls.push(url);

    if(images.length == x+1){
      // break out of loop and add the imagesUrls list to firestore
    }
  })
}
```

but what happens is that the code sometimes doesn't add all the image urls to the imageUrls list and I'll have only 1 or 2 image urls saved to firestore while in firestorage I see it uploaded all the images.

I understand that uploading takes some time and would like to know the best way to implement this as I assumed the .then() method is an async approach and would take care of any await instances.

Your response would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you get the values of `filepath` in the `for` block, but let's imagine that `images` is an array of fully qualified paths to the images you wish to upload to the bucket.

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
const signedURLs = [];

const promises1 = [];
images.forEach(path => {
    promises.push(admin.storage.bucket().upload(filepath, {options}))
})

Promise.all(promises1)
.then(uploadResponsesArray => {
    const promises2 = [];
    const config = {  // See https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl
        action: 'read',
        expires: '03-17-2025',
        //...
        };
    uploadResponsesArray.forEach(uploadResponse => {
        const file = uploadResponse[0];
        promises2.push(file.getSignedUrl(config))
    })
    return Promise.all(promises2);
})
.then(getSignedUrlResponsesArray => {
    signedURLs.push(getSignedUrlResponsesArray[0])
});

// Do whatever you want with the signedURLs array
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I haven't tested but will do. I was able to solve the problem by setting the if condition to check if the image file list(raw file) is equal to the image URL list instead of x+1 as stated my code.

//code preview
if(images.length == x+1) // replaced with
if(images.length == imageUrls.length)

But I strongly feel your answer would be a more suitable answer.